# DirectX 11 steam.dll overhead on Windows 7

Tags: directx-11, direct3d, steam, direct3d11

I have dx11 app which drops performance on win7 **when linked with steam.dll**.

App hangs in *dx11.device->CreateDeferredContext* for ~8ms in ~75% frames in main thread.

No such issue in app built without steam. Also cannot reproduce on win10.

I suspect that Steam hooks DirectX calls and does something to them, like adding additional synchronization or something.

Any help is appreciated.

App info:

- 32 bit app built on Windows 10 with visual studio 2017 (version 15.4.5)
- command buffers with deferred context are created each frame (hang is there)
- Swapchain present mode for Windows 7: *DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_SEQUENTIAL* with VSync

Problem environment:

- Lenovo laptop with Windows 7
- NVidia GeForce 840m with 378.66 driver
- DirectX feature level 11.0
- Disabling "steam overlay" in steam client settings doesn't help
- GPU frame time according to performance queries is low (~5ms)